# Format Date-time column without losing the Date-time data-type in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to format the date-time column to the given format. The only solution I came across in Python is via using 'strftime' which convert the **date-time** to **unicode**.

```
original = df.date
required_date_format ='%d/%m/%Y'

formatted = df.date.dt.strftime(required_date_format)
converted_after_formatting = pd.to_datetime(\
    df.date.dt.strftime(required_date_format),\
    format=required_date_format)
```

The outputs of the above code snippet are as follows:

[image: Outputs]

I want a solution that can format the date-time column without loosing it's data-type.

Comment: Give output as text , Please don't post the image

Comment: Do you want datetime in format `%d/%m/%Y` ? I think it is not possible in python.

Comment: Yes I want it in any format that user can identify via using these % literals. Require a generic solution.

Comment: Why would you need that? Pandas isnt really front-end. I'm not sure it can be done.

Comment: Sure @iamnewuser I will edit it I thought that would be a more descriptive way. Can you please suggest a sample way?

Comment: @roganjosh I need this functionality to be handled at back-end since formatting is the part of the functionality.

Comment: Use code format option , also please mention what is df which you imported !

Comment: But at the backend, you're just dealing with a standard datetime format. I'm not clear on why that needs to be presented in a particular way visually.

Comment: @iamnewuser Thanks. i will surely go through them.

Comment: @roganjosh It's the part of data wrangling where a user require that I want to format the date-time to a particular required format. So upon applying the formatting there must not be the change in data-type of that column. I can understand your point but in my case I am suppose to do it that way and looking for any available options since my research on it results in void. Thanks